# Java Winrm Tool can't connect to remote host

Tags: java, powershell, winrm

i'm trying to use Java WinrmTool to connect to a remote Windows host from my Java app that is running on Linux.

when hitting the executePs() method the app get stuck and eventually getting timed out. what am i doing wrong?

```
public WinRmToolResponse execute() {
    WinRmToolResponse resp = null;
    try {
        WinRmClientContext context = WinRmClientContext.newInstance();
        WinRmTool tool = WinRmTool.Builder.builder(this.address, this.userName,  this.currentPassword)
                .authenticationScheme(AuthSchemes.NTLM)
                .port(this.port)
                .useHttps(false)
                .context(context)
                .build();

        resp = tool.executePs(this.command);
        context.shutdown();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resp;
            
}
```

the remote host is Windows Server 2016 and the winrm config is the following:

```
MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
MaxTimeoutms = 60000
MaxBatchItems = 32000
MaxProviderRequests = 4294967
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = 10.21.191.
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;
    MaxConcurrentOperations =
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPe
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 24
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSec
    AllowUnencrypted = true
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = true
        CbtHardeningLevel = R
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = * [Source="G
    IPv6Filter = * [Source="G
    EnableCompatibilityHttpLi
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsL
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess =
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 100
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 10
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 204
    MaxShellsPerUser = 25
```

logs:

```
2021-05-23 12:54:31.617  INFO 30656 --- [nio-8885-exec-6] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd}WinRmService from WSDL: jar:file:/C:/Users/ostopiky/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.cloudsoft.windows/winrm4j-client/0.7.0/4768e5e75e97d54006d12595d20fbc648dda52ff/winrm4j-client-0.7.0.jar!/wsdl/WinRmService.wsdl
2021-05-23 13:11:46.398  WARN 30656 --- [nio-8885-exec-6] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for {http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd}WinRmService#{http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd}Receive has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not receive Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:65) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:440) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:355) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.receive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.RetryingProxyHandler.invokeWithRetry(RetryingProxyHandler.java:44) ~[winrm4j-client-0.7.0.jar:na]
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.RetryingProxyHandler.invoke(RetryingProxyHandler.java:34) ~[winrm4j-client-0.7.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.receive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.ShellCommand.receiveCommand(ShellCommand.java:112) ~[winrm4j-client-0.7.0.jar:na]
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.ShellCommand.execute(ShellCommand.java:91) ~[winrm4j-client-0.7.0.jar:na]
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool.executeCommand(WinRmTool.java:283) ~[winrm4j-0.7.0.jar:na]
    at bls.microservices.cptservice.service.CptService.executePsCommands(CptService.java:238) ~[main/:na]
    at bls.microservices.cptservice.service.CptService.domainAccountActions(CptService.java:211) ~[main/:na]
    at bls.microservices.cptservice.controllers.DomainAccountController.getAccountServices(DomainAccountController.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking https://10.164.28.49:5986/wsman: 120,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-31 [ACTIVE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1402) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1386) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit$AsyncWrappedOutputStream.close(AsyncHTTPConduit.java:417) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-hc-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:673) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 120,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-31 [ACTIVE]
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:261) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:502) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:211) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Comment: WinRM is disabled by standard on Windows. You're getting a timeout because the service is not running. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/how-to-enable-windows-remote-shell

Comment: thanks but the WinRM service is running on the remote

Comment: try closing a TCP handshake on the ports 80, 443, 5985 and 5986. Sorry if you already did, i'm trying to cover everything lol

Answer (score 0):

try with `AllowUnencrypted = true` and channel over HTTPS for encryption